# How do I run this function with GPU.js?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, gpu, gpu.js

I want to run this permutations function on GPU.

```
function* permute(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length;
  var c = Array(length).fill(0);
  var i = 1;
  var k;
  var p;

  yield permutation.slice();
  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i];
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      yield permutation.slice();
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
```

To run this on GPU I try to use https://gpu.rocks/ but I do not understand their example of how to setup the threads. How should I write this permutations function so I can run it in the browser on GPU?

Comment: Any feedback? please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

The GPU.js supports only a few operations, because it is translate to shaders. In the tests here you cannot use it to produce outputs longer than 100k elements.

The [operations supported](https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/#supported-math-functions) are very limited, you cannot assign to array elements for instance, and this is due to the nature of the underlying computation unit. Also you have to be aware of [branch divergence](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/branch-divergence).

Two steps were required to implement your function in a way that it could be used in a kernel.

1. **make it parallel**: Your implementation is iterative and each iteration builds a new result based on the result of the previous iteration. What I created instead is a function that given the iteration number `J` can produce a permutation.
2. **make it scalar and without array modification**: The function to compute permutation swaps elements on an array, thus requires assigning to array elements. To prevent that what I created is a loop where I track the locations of each the elements. If a given element ends at position `I` that element is returned. Notice that this function must be called once for each element in each permutation.

```js
const gpu = new GPU();
// For reference
// This is the function to compute the J'th permutation
// of N elements. Rewrited to create the kernel.
function permutation(J, N) {
  const arr = []
  for(let i = 0; i < N; ++i)arr[i] = i;
  let j = J;
  for(let i = 2; i <= N; ++i){
    let e1 = j % i;
    const t = arr[e1];
    arr[e1] = arr[i-1];
    arr[i-1] = t;
    j = (j - e1) / i;
  }
  return arr;
}

function permuteAt() {
  const N = this.constants.length;
  let I = N - this.thread.x - 1;
  let J = this.thread.y;
  
  for(let d = 0; d < N; ++d){
    // check if the I'th element of the J'th permutation is d
    let dPos = d;
    let j = J;
    let i = 0;
    for(let i = 2; i <= N; ++i){
      let e1 = j % i;
      let e2 = i - 1;
      // track the movements element d
      if(e1 == dPos){
        dPos = e2;
      }else if(e2 == dPos){
        dPos = e1;
      }
      j = (j - e1) / i;
    }
    // element d ended at position i
    // console.log(JSON.stringify({dPos, I, J, N, t: this.thread}))
    if(dPos == I){
      return d;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

// Run it in javascript
let result;
const t0Js = Date.now()
for(let i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
  result = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map(v => permuteAt.apply({
  thread: {x: i, y: v}, 
  constants: {length: 10}
  }))
}
const tfJs = Date.now();
console.log('time spend in javascript: ', (tfJs - t0Js)/10000);

const generatePermutations = gpu.createKernel(permuteAt).setOutput([10, 10000]).setConstants({length: 10});

const t0GPU = Date.now()
for(let i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
  const c = generatePermutations();
}
const tfGPU = Date.now();
console.log('time spend in gpu: ', (tfGPU - t0GPU)/10000/100);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gpu.js@latest/dist/gpu-browser.min.js"></script>
```